# How to embed PHP output into Typo3 6.x page content?

Tags: typo3

What is the best way to embed PHP script output (or PHP function output from my function which can access database) in page content?

More concretely I have a number of pages, where for example each country (a "real" page) needs to pull out info from the external database and output it into the content.

Do I need Fluid-something to do this with Typo3 6.x?

Comment: Your question is unclear, improve it if you want to get some sensible answer(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure, if I understand you correctly but most likely you want to do this kind of stuff in an extension with extbase and fluid.

Comment: Can you maybe provide a link to a simple example?